# How to retain existing images in a panel while redrawing in c#?

Tags: c#, image, panel, draw

I have a panel where I am drawing images on button click. But on the second button click, the previously drawn image is being replaced by the new Image.

```
void panel_Image_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
  {
   Point p1 = new Point(i, 0);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(Clipboard.GetImage(), p1);
   i += img.Width;
  }
}
```

I want to retain the previously drawn image in the panel, when the new image is being drawn. The clipboard is being refreshed on each button click with the new image. Any help would be highly appreciated!!!!
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the paint event actually works and what causes your images to disappear , but what you can try is adding your images to a list and then looping through the list to get all of your images displayed on the panel.
Try this code:

```
    int i = 0;
    List<Image> Images = new List<Image>();
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
        {
            Images.Add(Clipboard.GetImage());

            foreach (Image item in Images)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(item, new Point(i,0));
                i += Clipboard.GetImage().Width;

            }
        }
        i = 0;
     }
```

Don't forget to call the Invalidate function.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        panel1.Invalidate();
     }
```